# Do I need a read buffer for ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java

I have a JPA `AttributeConverter` for converted a `String` to a gzipped `byte[]` and back.

The convert-to method is fairly straight forward:

```
public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {

        gos.write(attribute.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        gos.finish();
        gos.flush();

        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

My question is around the convert-from method:

```
public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
    try (GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dbData));
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Given that the byte array `dbData` is already in memory, is there any point in the `buffer`? Is it not more "performant" to read byte-by-byte straight into the `baos` skipping the `buffer` altogether?

The buffer would make sense if the read method was making an underlying OS call, but its not here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that the byte array dbData is already in memory, is there any point in the buffer?

Buffers are used to improve performance.  They usually do improve performance compared to reading one byte at a time which is the only alternative here.

> Is it not more "performant" to read byte-by-byte straight into the baos skipping the buffer altogether?

Your bytes in the baos are compressed, if you could read those you wouldn't use the GZIPInputStream.

---

If you want efficiency, and simplicity I suggest you read/;write straight from/to the ByteArrayInput/OutputStream without using a byte[] at all.

```
public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String text) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                      new GZIPOutputStream(baos), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        out.write(text);
        out.close();    
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                         new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dbData)),
                         StandardCharsets.UTF_8) {

        char[] chars = new char[512];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0;)
            sb.append(chars, 0, len);

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

To simplify this, assuming your string doesn't contain a newline, you can do

```
public static byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String text) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                 new GZIPOutputStream(baos), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        out.write(text);
        out.write("\n");
        out.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

public static String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dbData)),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

        return br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = convertToDatabaseColumn("Hello world, 0123456789 0123456789");
    System.out.println(convertToEntityAttribute(bytes));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this slightly missing the point of the question? Using a `BufferedReader` is exactly the same thing right? (its using a buffer in the implementation). I've had a quick look at the implementation and it looks like there is a buffer in `GzipInputStream` anyways

Comment: @Cheetah and we use buffers when they improve performance.  It's not clear what you see as the alternative because you clearly cannot read the compressed data as if it was uncompressed.

Comment: there is an internal buffer in GzipInputStream (which has a read() method), I would have expected I could read byte-by-byte

Comment: @Cheetah correct, it has to copy data from the result of calling GZIPInputStream.  Note: InflatorInputStream/DeflatorOutputStream are slightly faster and smaller as GZIP wraps that stream and add a header/checksum

Comment: @Cheetah You can read byte-by-byte unless performance is important to you in which case you need a buffer.

Comment: @Cheetah Here is an example of the difference between reading byte-by-byte and reading using buffers.  Byte-by-byte: count to 1 billion with a unit of 1 (ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, ...).  Buffered: count to 1 billion with a unit of 1 million (ex. 1 million, 2 million, 3 million, ...).  Eventually, it will become clear that one of those counting techniques reaches 1 billion first (as in is more efficient).

Comment: @DwB - Is the underlying implementation that takes a buffer to read/write not going to be doing it byte-by-byte anyways?

Comment: @Cheetah when you use a buffer it doesn't have to process each byte individually, it can copy whole sections.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I think that is incorrect, if you follow the call stack down into the JDK code, eventually its calling `InputStream.read()` which readers bytes one-by-one....where are you seeing "copy whole sections"?

Comment: @Cheetah you must be running different code to me because when I run it I see called to read(byte[], int, int) where the length is 8192 bytes. The only byte-by-byte processing is the the multi-byte to char conversion (in the Java code at least)

Comment: @PeterLawrey you need to step further through the stack than that method call to see the byte-by-byte processing. (I see the same call as you do, but have stepped further into that method to make my "claim")

Comment: @Cheetah I have stepped at the way down to the native code. Can you point to a method in a class?

Comment: @Cheetah If I breakpoint InputStream.read() and read(byte[], int, int) I can see that read() is used to read bytes in the header AND tailer, however for the body it calls read(byte[],int,int)

Comment: @Cheetah if I use DeflatorOuputStream and InflatorInputStream, which I suggest you use as these don't have a header/tailer. InputStream.read() is not called.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `GZIPInputStream.read(byte[])` calls `FilterInputStream.read(byte[])` calls `FilterInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` calls `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` which reads byte-by-byte. The mistake I've made is that its not actually input stream, its `ByteArrayInputStream` which overrides the method and uses `System.arraycopy`...but how does this get a performance increase over iterating over the array?

Comment: @Cheetah System.arraycopy doesn't have to copy one byte at a time, but it can copy say 8 bytes by reading a `long`, or even 16 bytes at a time using the XMM registers (I suspect it is only 8).  Java 9 should have support for `Long2` which is a primitive which uses XMM registers are holds 128 bits.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - the dots have now been connected - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `dbData` and `buffer` represent different things. The first represents gzip'ed data, and the latter represents the un-gzipped, uncompressed data. There is most likely not even a one-to-one ratio of input bytes to output bytes; one would hope that the compressed data is significantly smaller than the output!